# Обновление Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: ubuntu

Не могу обновить Ubuntu 17.04. Знаю, что версия уже не поддерживается. 
Пробовал по [этому](http://kiman.odesa.in/2018/01/19/prekrashhena-podderzhka-ubuntu-17-04-ne-stavyatsya-programmy/) и по [этому](https://losst.ru/obnovlenie-ubuntu-do-17-10) методу. Никакого результата не получил.

При запуске из командной строки получаю следующее

`➜  ~ sudo do-release-upgrade
Проверка наличия нового релиза Ubuntu
Ваша версия  Ubuntu больше не поддерживается.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/do-release-upgrade", line 136, in <module>
    "%(url)s\n") % { 'url' : url })
ValueError: unsupported format character '?' (0xa) at index 55`

Куда идти, чего давить?

Comment: Ошибку гуглить пробовали?

Answer (score 2):

- [Ответ от пользователя SO](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release/91821#91821)
- [Официальная страница](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades#SpecificOlder) про обновления EOL дистрибутивов
- [Релизы Ubuntu](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases)

Обновлять нужно следуя версиям 17.04 > 17.10 > 18.04. Если это LTS то 16.04 > 18.04.

Если пропущено несколько выпусков, то можно и переустановить и затем восстановить свои файлы. Это быстрее и наверное даже надежнее, без "legacy" проблем.